# JQuery append to an element its own content

Tags: jquery, append

I would need to append a `<span>` element to an anchor element, with its content. Like this:

```
<div class="button"><a href="#">content text</a></div>
```

I need this:

```
<div class="button"><a href="#">content text<span>content text</span></a></div>
```

I try it in jQuery, but I can't put the content:

```
$('.butt a').append('<span>'+???+'</span>');
```

Please help me, if you can! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), like this:

```
$('.button a').append(function(i, html) { return '<span>'+html+'</span>'; });
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ewdd6/), or a bit safer DOM approach (what I'd go with):

```
$('.button a').append(function(i, html) { return $('<span />',{html:html}); });
```

[You can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ewdd6/1/). In both of the above cases the `html` the function receives is the current html/text inside the `<a>` you're appending to...which works out perfect here.

Comment: @Jonathon - I'd take another glance at the API since 1.4...a *lot* of methods got the "takes a method" treatment, can really cut down on code in many cases :)

Comment: will do, thanks :) Ahh - jQuery makes me love it more and more every day.

Comment: Yes, greate! I can use $(this).text() this way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because you're trying to select the `butt` class - but your class is `button`:

```
$('.button a').append('<span>Your span text here</span>');
```

Comment: I think you missed the question ;) He's asking how to *dynamically* get that content, you have it hard-coded.

Comment: Ah true. Wasn't sure if he was asking about the dynamic bit (which I didn't realise about the append function, nice touch) or just the error with the class :)

Comment: No worries! At least Nick had the answer for you (and I learnt something new). Win/win all round :)